# Cannot import const React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, components

Not sure what is going on. I am literally following a tutorial step-by-step. Below are my files. However I have added 'export' before 'const App' since I was getting errors: `'App' is declared but its value is never read.` And the `export` seems to cause the warning to go away. But upon running the code, regardless if the `export` is there or not I receive the same message when I `yarn start`:

```
 '/src/index.js
Attempted import error: './containers/app' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').'
```

**src/containers/app/index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../home'
import About from '../about'

export const App = () => (
  <div>
    <header>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/about-us">About</Link>
    </header>

    <main>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about-us" component={About} />
    </main>
  </div>
)
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import store, { history } from "./store";
import App from "./containers/app";

import "./index.css";

const target = document.querySelector("#root");

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exporting your App component as a named export, but trying to import it as a default import. if you add brackets to the *App* in your import statement, as I've demonstrated below, it should all work.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import store, { history } from "./store";
-> add brackets here import { App } from "./containers/app"; <--

import "./index.css";

const target = document.querySelector("#root");

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <App />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
);
```

Alternatively, if you want to use a default export (which I think is what you were originally trying to do), you need to add a default export to the end of your App.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../home' 
import About from '../about'

 const App = () => (
  <div>
    <header>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/about-us">About</Link>
    </header>

    <main>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/about-us" component={About} />
    </main>
  </div>
)

export default App
```

Comment: neither one of the above suggestions worked. And as I mentioned, 'export' was added to satisfy some warning saying (const App: () => JSX.Element)). Muskett, i had hope for your answer and tried, with and without, the 'export' before the 'const App'

Comment: @SC4RECROW - I have updated my answer with another potential solution, let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what the error says. It's expected that `App` is default export:

```
import App from "./containers/app";
```

But `App` is named export:

```
export const App = () => (
  ...
)
```

If it's supposed to be used as default export, it should be exported as:

```
export default () => (
  ...
)
```

Comment: I know, I added the import to satisfy the warning (const App: () => JSX.Element). Even with the 'export' omitted, it doesnt want to seem to work. Your default suggestion didnt help either

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <header>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/about-us">About</Link>
        </header>

        <main>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/about-us" component={About} />
        </main>
     </div>
   )

export default App;
```